# PHP's strpos() not working and always getting into the if condition

Tags: php, strpos

I'm trying to check if a specific character is not present in a string in my code and apparently php doesn't care about anything and always gets inside the if

```
foreach($inserted as $letter)
{
    if(strpos($word, $letter) !== true) //if $letter not in $word
    {
        echo "$word , $letter, ";
        $lives--;
    }
}
```

In this case $word is "abc" and $letter is "b", I've tried changing a lot of random things like from true to false and things like that but I can't get it, can anyone help me please?

Comment: That's because [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) _never_ returns `true`.

Comment: i know, that's why i've been using the double = (!==)

Comment: You're misunderstanding. `strpos()` doesn't have any state where it _can_ return `true`. It's an invalid return value for that function. You might as well have written: `if (strpos($word, $letter) !== 'FooBarHelloWorld')`. The function only returns `false` (if the string isn't found) or an integer (from `0` and up) with the position of the needle in the haystack.

Comment: @EgidioPignataro What Magnus means, is that strpos will never return `true`, so because your `if` statement is checking for "not true" (and strpos will never return true), it will always enter your if block.

Comment: so i should try if(strpos($word, $letter) === false) instead?

Comment: strpos() Returns the position of the first occurrence of a string inside another string, or `FALSE` if the string is not found.

Comment: i've tried with  if(strpos($word, $letter) === false) and it's now working, thanks a lot!

Comment: _Suggestion:_ If you're having any doubts about a PHP function in the future, start by checking the [manual](https://php.net) and read what the return values are.

Answer (score 4):

Changing the way you validate should fix it, like below:

```
     foreach($inserted as $letter)
        {
            //strpos returns false if the needle wasn't found
            if(strpos($word, $letter) === false) 
            {
                echo "$word , $letter, ";
                $lives--;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Others seem to have given the same answer: Magnus Eriksson

Comment: Ok? Thanks for letting me know, I guess? :-p

Comment: @lucid Only 1 other answer that is newer and comments are not answers.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(strpos($word, $letter) === false) //if $letter not in $word
{
    echo "$word , $letter, ";
    $lives--;
}
```

also, be careful to check explicitly against `false`, [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) can return `0` (a falsey value) if the match is in the 0th index of the string...

for example

```
if (!strpos('word', 'w') {
    echo 'w is not in word';
}
```

would output the, possibly confusing, message `'w is not in word'`